# What is a stream of JSON objects called?

Tags: json

Is there a format which consists of a sequence of JSON blobs, separated by some delimiter?

For example, here are some JSON blobs separated by newlines:

```
{"first":"message"}
["second","message"]
"third message"
```

Does this format have a name?

Comment: Do you still accept new lines in your JSON strings or did you restrict the JSON norm (which might seem ok for your use) ?

Comment: Either way. I'm open to formats that restrict the use of newlines in the messages, or ones that allow pretty-printed JSON.

Comment: It's called invalid JSON syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Line delimited JSON appears to be a Real Thing:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_Delimited_JSON

Comment: That article was written today.

Comment: Hah, how about that. That's a bit of a coincidence.

Comment: .. and it seems that the page uses your blog from 2009 as a reference. Been sitting on this question for a while, huh?

Comment: @antiduh Not a coincidence :)  I wrote it to clarify what a few developers were doing, after not getting an answer I liked on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6573870/choice-of-transports-for-json-over-tcp I also emailed jimbojw as his page talked about something similar http://trephine.org/t/index.php?title=Newline_delimited_JSON

Comment: Yeah, so @chrisdew reached out to me to see what if I had a better name than the ones we'd come up with. I thought SO would be a good place to ask. I didn't realize it would reinforce existing opinions on the matter. Do you know of any other non-us references to this technology and what it might be called?

Comment: Hrm.  "JSON document" seems to be out, since plenty of people seem to equate document == object.